# How to add queryPrams with previous query into next js router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

here suppose I have a dynamic router like `[index]` under category folder. Here dynamic index will be category slug. Now I have to add more query prams in this url.

First link will be like-

`/category/men-and-women`

Now I have to add to this url some query with `router.push` method will be like-

`/category/men-and-women?soryBy=price`

Then I have to also add some more query prams with this previous url like-

`/category/men-and-women?sortyBy=price&maxPrice=1232`

How can I add more and more query prams with previously stored prams?

I tried two ways-

```
router.push({
    pathname: `/category/${router.query.index}`,
    query: {
        minPrice: value[0],
        maxPrice: value[1]
    }
})
```

It works good. But when I try to add more query prams. I am stacking-

```
router.push({
    pathname: router.asPath,
    query: {
        sortBy: "price"
    }
})
```

I try it by this way. But it not working.

Comment: Keep in mind that `router.asPath` returns the current paths with the query parameters. You may need to extract the path segment only and remove the params from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current params and append them:

```
const router = useRouter();

// ...

router.push({
    pathname: router.asPath,
    query: {
        ...router.query,
        sortBy: "price"
    }
})
```

Comment: Not working properly!

Comment: @MdAli Try replacing `router.asPath` with `router.asPath.split('?')[0]`.